# Merge {hyperlink} and {links}

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

I suggest to merge the tags [hyperlink](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink) and[links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/links). They mean the same here.

The [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/link) reports:

> 1.5  short for hyperlink

**Update:**
There is also a similar tag [cross-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-referencing). Should we add "avoid the tag **links** and use **hyperlink** or **cross-referencing** instead" to links?

Comment: [tag:links] might also refer to cross references in the document.  Even though similar, a [tag:hyperlink] usually refers to an external resource.  So I don't think they mean the same: -1

Comment: If you want to suggest a tag synonym, just go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/links/synonyms or https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/hyperlink/synonyms and make a proposal.

Comment: @JouleV thank you. I searched for this functionality, without success. Now, I have not enough points on `link`

Comment: @HenriMenke I looked it up in the oxford dictionary. Looks to me, that it is really the same. I am glad there are no tags for cyberlink and link4.0 on .sx yet. ;-)

Comment: @HenriMenke Interesting... Is that a well known distinction so that people can be reasonably expected to (want to) differentiate the two? Does the distinction make sense for our (La)TeX purposes? I assume most [tag:link] and [tag:hyperlink] question would ultimately come down to `hyperref`. I also note that the [tag:links] wiki has said "links is specifically about dealing with hyperlinks." for a long time...

Comment: @moewe and JonasStein It is completely irrelevant what the dictionary or the tag wiki says.  The only thing of interest is how people *use* the tag.  As long as questions about cross references are tagged with [tag:links], it cannot be merged with [tag:hyperlink].

Comment: @HenriMenke Mhhh, I'm not sure if tagging can *only* be judged by current usage. It seems to be a sentiment [shared by some](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/how-to-encourage-people-to-send-bug-reports-instead-of-using-sx-as-kind-of-bugtr#comment25872_8171) on this site that tagging is not entirely accurate and a bit of hit and miss. I'm not entirely convinced that the tag wiki and dictionaries should have no role here, surely the tag wiki should give guidance about tag usage and surely people use their understanding about the (dictionary) meaning of words to decide how to tag

Comment: ... Ultimately I think the question is whether there is a substantial difference between *link* and *hyperlink* in the TeX world that seems worth preserving. Especially if the difference goes against common usage of the word (dictionary) or the guidance in the tag wiki. At the moment I'm not convinced there is such a difference. But I think that there might be an argument in saying that the synonym would require extensive re-tagging and would not be worth it.

Comment: @HenriMenke If users use the tag for anything it is the best to define the tag properly. I think it is good to make a cut and add `link is not crossreferences` (or `link is a synonym of crossreferences`).

Comment: I voted here https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/links/synonyms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree link and hyperlink should be merged. the tag wiki for link says explicitly it is about hyperlinks, and I don't think (this century) people do (or should) refer to non hyperlinked cross references as "links".

I don't think the suggested distinction that hyperlink should only be used for external references is valid.  An in-document link is a hyperlink.